# TFS Merging Development Branch to Main

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

Our team started using TFS few months back and we are learning as we progress.  We first checked in our existing code to TFS thereby creating a Main Branch. We then created a Development Branch from this Main branch.

We just did a release and I merged Development branch with Main. It asked me to map Main branch folder on my workstation. Done that Merge completed successfully. But after merge I noticed on server that change sets are still old and source code on server has not changed.
looking further I noticed that the changed file is marked as 'merge pending'.

When I opened solution from mapped folder of main branch, I did see that all changes from Development branch merged to Main are in pending state.

**Questions**

1. Do I always have to check in pending changes after each merge in  TFS
2. Is is possible to merge source code on server instead of from
   workstation (All code in development is in Checked in state).

I am using VS2012 (if that matters)

Please advise, especially if I am taking a wrong approach with TFS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In answer to your questions:

1. Yes, you always have to check in pending changes. Pending changes are local to your machine, they give you the chance to review the result of the merge locally before they are committed to the server. This is especially important because the merge may result in a conflict that you need to resolve before you can check in.
2. I don't think that this is possible (although I never researched this specific question). This is, again, because of the possibility of a conflict that needs to be resolved manually. Even if you perform a merge programmatically via the TFS API, the merge will happen locally.

Don't worry, you are doing the right thing. Only one word of warning regarding merges in general: Before you attempt a merge, always make sure that you perform a "get latest" operation on the target branch! The source branch does not need to be up-to-date on your local machine because the merge operation will get the source branch data from the server. But the changes will be merged with whatever version your local target branch files have, so if these are not up-to-date you will get unexpected results.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was afraid I had may be set some option wrong.